# how to take compiled code(like C) and use it as a python module

Tags: python, c

say i have some code in C which is fast and specific but i want to manage how its called in python .i have seen python modules written in c like numpy how would i do that? and is this possible for all compiled languages like rust/go etc.

for example i have a really fast custom database orm in c++ with multithreading and all that good stuff. how would i convert it into a python library and use it?
i would like this as python isn't as fast as or as versatile as C++ etc.

if this is possible how does it work in the back ?

Comment: The official docs list 3 options (custom Python module, `ctypes` or `cffi`): https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html

Answer (score 9):

**Here are the steps:**

- Write file in C
- Compile and generate shared library (`.so`)
- Load using ctypes
- Call those methods

**More detailed answer:**

*Write file in C:*

```c
// test.c
int add_numbers(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

*Compile and generate shared library*:

```bash
gcc -shared -o test.so test.c
```

*Load using ctypes*:

```py
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL('./test.so')
```

*Call those methods (This step has the most overhead)*

```py
lib.add_numbers.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int)
lib.add_numbers.restype = ctypes.c_int

result = lib.add_numbers(3, 4)
print(result)
```

**Good read:**

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface
- Web search: NABI (Native Application Binary Interface)

**NB: doing this for a DB will require lots of attention, and experiment; as you need to compile it. Trust me it takes lots of time. Then you need to add these method wrapper in Python.**

*Yes, you can do the opposite also, you need to have `<Python.h>` header in your program. But trust me, it's more work. But if it required for some reason, yeah there is atleast a way, of course.*